# jQuery slider does not work with DotNetNuke module

Tags: jquery, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have used the s3Slider jquery plugin to create nice banner animations in both html and asp.net pages. here is the link to plugin: 
http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/demonstration.html

However when i try to use it inside a dot net nuke ascx control it does not work at all. 
Maybe i have to change the code but I have no idea because i am fairly new to dnn.
any advice welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- start integrating the css, rename the css to module.css
- convert the divs of the slider to repeater template
- add reference to plugin script at the top of the ascx control.

After completing above steps, you will only have some problems because of css rules overriding each other as there are lots of other css in dnn.